# Socket.io connecting but not emitting or listening with electron.js

Tags: javascript, socket.io, electron

I'm trying to make a chat program using electron.js and socket.io, but while my socket.io code works perfectly when I test it in the console or browser, once I load it into electron code the sockets only connect, they can't receive or emit data.

Here's my code

server.js

```
var port = 8321

var io = require('socket.io').listen(port);
console.log('listening on *:' + port);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
    io.emit('bar', "Greetings from the server");

    socket.on('chat_message', function(msg1) {
        console.log(msg1);
        socket.emit('chat_message', "Reply from server");
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

view.js (Client)

```
let $ = require('jquery') 

$('#messages').append($('<li>').text("Initial setup"));

const io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8321');

$('form').submit(function(){
    var msg = $('#m').val();
    if (!msg) {
        return false;
    }

    socket.emit('chat_message', msg);
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text("You sent: "+msg));
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);                 
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
});

socket.on('bar', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text("Received: "+msg));
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
});
```

index.js (For loading electron)

```
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800, 
        height: 600, 
        transparent : true,
        frame:false
    })

    mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }))

    mainWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true);
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

client1.js (Test client in console that works)

```
var io2 = require('socket.io-client');
var socket2 = io2.connect('http://localhost:8321');


var msg2 = "Greetings from client1";
socket2.emit('chat_message', msg2);


socket2.on('bar', function(msg){
    console.log('Received message from server:' + msg);
});
```

Comment: Please include any error messages or other useful info so we can. Help debug and fix the issue.

Comment: There were no error messages. Nothing showed up.

Comment: Can you post it on Github?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters What is wrong with delegating it to the main process? This in my mind is how it is supposed to be done in Electron...